# UWP/WinRT: How to access a control generated by a template from the item it is bound to?

Tags: xaml, data-binding, windows-runtime, c++-cx, uwp

I have a Pivot whose contents are generated using data binding. For each Item in a vector, a Grid is generated, and within each grid a TextBlock is generated.

If I have a particular Item from the vector, how can I access the corresponding TextBlock that was generated from it in my code behind?

My first idea was to set the `x:name` property for each TextBlock to be a unique identifier held within each Item, and then I could simply call `FrameworkElement::FindName()` on the identifier, but apparently the `x:name` property isn't permitted to be generated using data binding.

I see that it's possible to go in the other direction, and pull up the Item from a TextBlock by calling its DataContext.

I'm seeing I could maybe use VisualTreeHelper to start searching for the TextBlock control by control. I'm having trouble locating examples in C++, though, how is this used in this context? Is this the only way to do it? It seems very involved for something so simple. Is there are more ways to do it, what's the correct way to do it?

I'm using C++/CX with XAML.

Comment: Maybe you should think more out of the box. Why do you want to access the TextBlock? Changing element properties can be done using triggers, behaviors or data binding with converters. Using these ways I could solve all problems which would've required accessing the UIElement from code.

Comment: Btw this ^: is there a reason not to use databinding with the textblock's text as well? It'd be much simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pivot is a descendant of ItemsControl, therefore:

Use https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.containerfromitem.aspx or https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.containerfromindex.aspx and plus the VisualTreeHelper. (If the ItemTemplate is fixed, you can even do something like `((Grid)*YourReturnedDependencyObject*).Children[0] as TextBlock`, so you don't even need the VisualTreeHelper.)

Comment: I accepted your answer, but I was wondering if you could take a look at my solution I also posted based on your advice and see if it makes sense? Are containers and the VisualTree clearly documented anywhere? If you look at my solution, I had to traverse two layers of unknown items in order to reach my TextBlock. However, in my XAML, the TextBlock is a direct child of the Grid. I figured all this out with painful trial and error testing out each item at each level, but what was the expected way for me to have arrived at this solution?

Comment: Those two unknown items are the ItemContainerTemplate's elements. (Link to this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299144.aspx ) Before with VS2013 you had to use some external tools like XamlSpy, but with 2015 you now have built-in live xaml debugger. With that, you can see the xaml tree runtime. (If you have some experience with html, this is a bit like the "shadow dom".)

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of anyone else who may be in a similar situation, here is the solution I ended up implementing, but I am marking Tamás Deme's answer as accepted, since it led me to this result.

```
// I am using dynamic_casts to determine if a returned object is of the expected class
auto currentPivotItem = dynamic_cast<PivotItem^>(myPivot->ContainerFromItem(myItem));
if (currentPivotItem != nullptr && VisualTreeHelper::GetChildrenCount(currentPivotItem) > 0)
{
    auto currentGrid = dynamic_cast<Grid^>(VisualTreeHelper::GetChild(currentPivotItem, 0));
    if (currentGrid != nullptr && VisualTreeHelper::GetChildrenCount(currentGrid) == 1)
        { // Through trial and error, I discovered there are 2 layers of unknownItems I need to traverse
        auto unknownItem = VisualTreeHelper::GetChild(currentGrid, 0);
        if (unknownItem != nullptr && VisualTreeHelper::GetChildrenCount(unknownItem) == 1)
            {
            auto unknownItem2 = VisualTreeHelper::GetChild(unknownItem, 0);
            if (unknownItem2 != nullptr && VisualTreeHelper::GetChildrenCount(unknownItem2) == 2)
                { // Based on my XAML, the TextBlock will always be the child at index 1
                auto currentTextBlock = dynamic_cast<TextBlock^>(VisualTreeHelper::GetChild(unknownItem2, 1));
                if (currentTextBlock != nullptr) currentTextBlock->Text = "Success!"
            }
        }
    }
}
```